# Can I use a same developer account to explore different Youtube channel (By Youtube Analytic API)

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api

I have three different youtube channels that have different purpose. But I only have one developer account.

After I tried to link to one of them with permission. I expected I can link to different channel with new project on GCP but it still return the first channel I linked to the Youtube Analytics.

Wondering if there's any methods that able to switch different YT channels in YT Analytic API.

```
client_tw = Analytics.with_secrets("client_sercets\client_secrets.json")
client_news = Analytics.with_secrets("client_sercets\client_secrets_news.json")
```

Comment: please edit your question and include [example] of how you are authorizing your code.  YouTube api is channel based not user based so you You need to login and authorize each channel.  You need an access token for each one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.